# Gödel's Incompleteness Theorem in "Gödel, Escher, Bach"

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, incompleteness

**Ok, so I'm reading the chapter on Gödel's Incompleteness Theorem in "Gödel, Escher, Bach" and I want to make sure I'm getting this right: the idea of the book's proof is to form the sentence**

"There exists no $a,a'$ with both (1) $a$ being the Gödel number of the derivation of the sentence having $a'$ as its Gödel number, and (2) $a'$ being the Gödel number of the sentence

"There exists no $a,a'$ with both (1) $a$ being the Gödel number of the derivation of the sentence having $a'$ as its Gödel number, and (2) $a'$ being the Gödel number of the sentence produced by substituting the free variables of the sentence with Gödel number $u$ by $u$"",

**where $u$ is the Gödel number of the sentence**

"There exists no $a,a'$ with both (1) $a$ being the Gödel number of the derivation of the sentence having $a'$ as its Gödel number, and (2) $a'$ being the Gödel number of the sentence produced by substituting the free variables of the sentence with Gödel number $a''$ by $a''$",

**$a''$ being free. Since this $a'$ actually exists, (we do indeed have a sentence to Gödel number), then the whole thing is the same as**

"There exists no $a$ with $a$ being the Gödel number of the derivation of the sentence

"There exists no $a,a'$ with both (1) $a$ being the Gödel number of the derivation of the sentence having $a'$ as its Godel number, and (2) $a'$ being the Godel number of the sentence produced by substituting the free variables of the sentence with Gödel number $u$ by $u$""

**But the sentence produced by substituting the free variables of the sentence with Gödel number $u$ by $u$ is**

"There exists no $a,a'$ with both (1) $a$ being the Gödel number of the derivation of the sentence having $a'$ as its Gödel number, and (2) $a'$ being the Gödel number of the sentence produced by substituting the free variables of the sentence with Gödel number $u$ by $u$",

**so that we get the original sentence is equivalent to**

"There exists no $a$ with $a$ being the Gödel number of the derivation of the sentence

"There exists no $a,a'$ with both (1) $a$ being the Gödel number of the derivation of the sentence having $a'$ as its Gödel number, and (2) $a'$ being the Gödel number of the sentence

"There exists no $a,a'$ with both (1) $a$ being the Gödel number of the derivation of the sentence having $a'$ as its Gödel number, and (2) $a'$ being the Gödel 
number of the sentence produced by substituting the free variables of the sentence with Gödel number $u$ by $u$.""";

**but the last two paragraphs are exactly the original sentence, so we finally get**

"There exists no $a$ with $a$ being the Gödel number of the derivation of this sentence".

**So this sentece must be true (otherwise we get a contradiction) and therefore not provable.**

**Is this all right?**

Comment: You can see [Gödel's Incompleteness Theorems](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/goedel-incompleteness/) : G's Theorem proves that, for a "suitable" theory $T$ : $T \vdash G_T \leftrightarrow \lnot \exists x Prf_T(x, \ulcorner G_T \urcorner)$. This means that in the thery $T$ we can build a sentence $G_T$ (the "Gödel's sentence") which is equivalent to a sentence expressing the "unprovability" of $G_T$. Thus, if $G_T$ was provable in $T$, we can express this fact in $T$ and thus we have $\exists x Prf_T(x, \ulcorner G_T \urcorner)$. But proving $G_T$ allows us to "detach" the ... 1/2

Comment: ... RHS of the biconditional, i.e. prove also : $\lnot \exists xPrf_T(x, \ulcorner G_T \urcorner)$ ==> **CONTRADICTION !!** Conclusion : $G_T$ is **not** provable in $T$. 2/2